# php http request

Tags: php, http, httpwebrequest

```
$post_data = array(
        'url' => $all[2],
        'op' => 'sv',
        'sid' => 1
    );
// Send a request to example.com 
$result = post_request('http://www.yahoo.com', $post_data);

function PostRequest($url) { 
    $opts = array('http' =>
        array(
            'method'  => 'GET',
            'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n"."Accept-language: en\r\n" .
              "Cookie: member_id=8593099\r\n" .
              "Cookie: pass_hash=fad917fe75e1059f85fc6d9bb6f7a19f\r\n".
              "Cookie: session_id=279fe56fd87e5371dc7e1c9f66c27522"
        )
    );
    $context  = stream_context_create($opts);
    $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
    return $result; 
}
```

I am able to send the request, but my action needs login to be performed.
Even once I'm logged in, it classifies me as not logged in.

I'm using localhost to send out the request. Is that because of the different domain?
I already copied the login cookies for my localhost, but it is still not working.
Any ideas?
What I tried to do is send http request with php.
My request has sent out, but my destination cannot detect cookies, and claim I am not login.

Comment: I'm finding it hard to understand your question. Are you trying to send post data to example.com, but it's not working because example.com requires you to be logged in?

Comment: `post_request` - what's that function doing? Unless you don't provide any specifics about it (are you using a library / framework / cms?), your question can not be answered. Additionally you might have overseen that yahoo requires cookies for logins.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure what you're trying to accomplish, as the code you've posted isn't quite clear. `post_request()` isn't a native PHP-function, so you'd have to give us a sample of it for us to be able to help you further.

I would however recommend that you've check that you've put `session_start();` way up top in your PHP-files - it ensures that you're able to access the session/cookie.

Comment: sorry i too rush to post this post.. i will add in further information